# Android start casting to a device chosen from a custom Cast Dialog

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have setup a custom Cast Dialog and added it using:

```
castButton.setDialogFactory(new DialogFactory());
```

My custom dialog retrieves available cast devices using the below code and display them as a list

```
MediaRouter.getInstance(getContext()).getRoutes();
```

How can I start casting to a `CastDevice` chosen from the above list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using:

`MediaRouter.getInstance(context).selectRoute(route)`

To disconnect I did:

`MediaRouter.getInstance(context).unselect(MediaRouter.UNSELECT_REASON_DISCONNECTED)`